# ADO.NET - Error reading multiple xml files

Tags: c#, ado.net, xmlreader, memorystream

I'm trying to read data from multiple XML files, but encountering the following exception :

**"Unexpected XML declaration. The XML declaration must be the first node in the document, and no white space characters are allowed to appear before it. 
Line 11895, position 3."**

In this case, there are 3 files i'm trying to read in a loop. If each file is read individually, it works fine. Its only when the the files are read consecutively in a loop, the exception occurs while reading the 2nd file. In the exception above, file1 had 11895 rows, so when reading file2 it throws 'Unexpected XML declaration at line 11895', because each file has its own XML declaration.

My question is : If a new DataSet and MemoryStream object is being used to read each file, then why is it not allowing the 2nd and 3rd file to have XML declaration headers ? How do I make each reading independent of the earlier one ?

Here is my code :

```
//Open the database connection
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ApplicationServices))
{
    cn.Open();
    // Begin a new transaction
    using (SqlTransaction tr = cn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            //Loop through each attachment, convert the attachment xml to DataTable and Load into the Database
            foreach (Attachment att in message.Attachments)
            {
                LogMessage(string.Format("Reading Attachment: {0}", att.Name), 0);
                // Load the Contents of the attachment into a MemoryStream
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(att.Content, true))
                {
                    ms.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    //Use a dataset to automatically determine the schema from the XML file
                    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
                    {
                        //Load the MemoryStream contents into a DataSet, that automatically determines the schema
                        try
                        {
                            ds.ReadXml(ms);
                            ms.Dispose();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            LogMessage(string.Format("Error reading xml {0}. {1}{2}", att.Name, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace), 2);
                            throw ex;
                        }

                        LogMessage(string.Format("Found {0} records", ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count), 0);

                        /*Other business logic to process data in the ds.Tables[0] ... */
                    }
                }
            }

            //Commit transaction if everything worked out fine
            LogMessage("Card product import complete, committing transaction", 0);
            tr.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage("Error Occured during card product import, rolling back transaction", 2);
            tr.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    cn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your DataSet can read only one xml file at a time.

```
 ds.ReadXml(ms);
```

Try if you can get all 3 xml files through XmlReader. That will tell you something.

Comment: I tried XmlDocument.Parse(MemoryStream) but that too has the same issue !